# how to cast string field to various data type in stored procedure

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

i have made one stored procedure to update value by column name to correspond column value.

here are :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmailField]
(
    @Email_id int,
    @var_name varchar(25),
    @var_value varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @var_name = 'Title'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [Title] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'Body'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [Body] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'ToUser'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [ToUser] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'IsFileAttached'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [IsFileAttached]  = CAST(@var_value AS BIT) WHERE (Id = @Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'SentDateTime'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [SentDateTime]  = CAST(@var_value AS DATETIME) WHERE (Id = @Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'TotalFileSize' 
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master]  SET [TotalFileSize] = CAST (@var_value AS BIGINT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
END
```

this works fine few day ago.

but now i faced one error called :

```
Could Not Translate value(DataClasses).UpdateEmailField(4,"TotalFileSize","0")
```

from linqtosql class.

i just want to solve this problem.

Is there any one to solve this problem.

```
-------------------------Update-----------------------
```

here is how i call this stored procedure :

```
db.UpdateEmailField(newId, "TotalFileSize", tot_file_size.ToString());
```

Comment: Ca i do wrong cast to string value to Bigint data type at last ELSE IF

Comment: can you show LinQ code?